# How to access string using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to write a function which returns the middle character of a string. I want it to work like the code below :

```
"123456789".midChar(); // Returns 5
"hello".midChar(); // returns 1
"test".midChar(); // returns e
```

I want to know how can I access the string if the function takes no parameters?
How can I refer to the strings inside of the function to be able to manipulate it? For example "123456789"

What have I done before asking this question?

I read about prototypes and understood how I can add methods to the array and string prototype. I tried to find the implementation of `String.prototype.charAt()` and several other ones to understand how it's built, but couldn't find one. All i was able to find is Reduce, ForEach and several other Array methods, but that wasn't very helpful to my case.

Comment: Inside the prototype, the string will be set as the context, so you can access it via `this`.

Comment: Why does it have to be a method on String rather than a plain function that takes a string as an argument?

Comment: Just for educational purposes, i want to know how prototypes work in depth, so im trying to build this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this` inside midChar function to access the string.

```js
String.prototype.midChar = function() {
  var mid = parseInt((this.length - 1) / 2)
  return this.substring(mid, mid+1);
}

console.log("123456789".midChar())
console.log("hello".midChar())
console.log("test".midChar())
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are returning "this.substring(mid, mid+1)" instead of doing "return this[mid];" ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
String.prototype.midChar= function () {
    console.log(String(this)); // 'this' is the string representation.
    console.log(this.substring(5));
    console.log(this);
};

"EleFromStack".midChar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

extend the prototype like this

```
String.prototype.midChar= function () {
    //put yout function body here..
    //i.e.
    //var firstchar = this.charAt(0)
};
```

that should do it!

Comment: Yes, that wasnt my question. My question is how i can access the string inside of this function